# sphinx search library new records are not showing

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using sphinx search library for indexing in my project.But i am unable to get all records.[Here you can see the results I get](http://www.dramazine.co.uk/search/groups/all?field=members&orderby=desc)
.I am having total 57 records but it is showing 24 records only. I have did research allot. It might be issue of real time indexing or something else.

If anyone has solution for this. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did run [indexer](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/ref-indexer.html), did not you?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of query did you run, could you please show snippet.
Also, you could check index directly is it contain 57 records or not using search command.
See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.6.html#ref-search

Comment: I have checked with search command without sphinx it is returning 57 records but i am using sphinx then i am only getting 24 always. Query  is simple not complex.

Comment: As Iaroslav suggested, if you could show us the search call, that'd be helpful. Also, it's worth noting Sphinx paginates search results to 20 (though this default can be changed) - are you aware of this?